# Building socket.io C++ with boost libraries

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, socket.io, cmake

Guys, I'm facing a little problem here. Basically, I'm trying to build this wonderful library https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp with CMake.

First of all, I installed boost as a required and it went to opt/local/include/boost and opt/local/lib. But the problem is that CMake couldn't find required boost libraries. After `Configure` CMake gave me that log:

```
not define build type, set to release
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1753 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.59.0

  Boost include path: /opt/local/include

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_date_time
          boost_random

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

Once I faced that problem, I tried to setup BOOST_LIBRARYDIR in hands, but that didn't work either.

Here's CMake file which goes with library which I unsuccessfully tried to compile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(sioclient)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" OFF)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS "Use Boost static version" ON)

set(MAJOR 1)
set(MINOR 6)
set(PATCH 0)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
MESSAGE(STATUS "not define build type, set to release" )
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )
elseif(NOT (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release" OR ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug" ))
MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE must be either Release or Debug")
return()
endif()

set(BOOST_VER "1.55.0" CACHE STRING "boost version" )

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) 
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VER} REQUIRED COMPONENTS system date_time random) 

aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src ALL_SRC)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/internal ALL_SRC)
file(GLOB ALL_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.h )
set(SIO_INCLUDEDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

add_library(sioclient ${ALL_SRC})
target_include_directories(sioclient PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/websocketpp 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/rapidjson/include
)

set_property(TARGET sioclient PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET sioclient PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
target_link_libraries(sioclient PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
set_target_properties(sioclient
    PROPERTIES
        SOVERSION ${MAJOR}
        VERSION ${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}
    )
endif()
list(APPEND TARGET_LIBRARIES sioclient)

find_package(OpenSSL)
if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
add_library(sioclient_tls ${ALL_SRC})
target_include_directories(sioclient_tls PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/websocketpp 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/rapidjson/include
    ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

set_property(TARGET sioclient_tls PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET sioclient_tls PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
target_link_libraries(sioclient_tls PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} )
target_compile_definitions(sioclient_tls PRIVATE -DSIO_TLS)
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
set_target_properties(sioclient_tls
    PROPERTIES
        SOVERSION ${MAJOR}
        VERSION ${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}
    )
endif()
list(APPEND TARGET_LIBRARIES sioclient_tls)

endif()

install(FILES ${ALL_HEADERS} 
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/include"
)

install(TARGETS ${TARGET_LIBRARIES}
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
)

install(FILES ${Boost_LIBRARIES} 
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
)
```

I appreciate any help here, guys! And one observation: if I'm not wrong, it tries to find `boost_random` when in `include` folder it has the name `random`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Looks like your boost installations is incomplete (`Could not find the following static Boost libraries:`).

Comment: Make sure that you've built Boost libraries statically (it can be disabled by default).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you haven't build static versions of Boost libraries.

If you've built Boost using Boost.Build (`b2` program), then you should recompile it with `link=static,shared` (run `b2 link=static,shared <other_flags>`) flag set, so that both dynamic and static libraries will be built.

**upd:** Also, this project's readme says that you should run your CMake with `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/opt/local -DBOOST_VER:STRING=<your boost version> ./` with appropriate Boost version specified.

Comment: Hello, nightuser! Ok, I'll give it a shot and get back to you shortly. Thank you for advice!